# PyQt5 adding additional widgets to a widget subclass using layouts?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to subclass a `QListWidget` and add a searchbox above it. I know I could create this by subclassing a `QWidget` and giving it a layout containing both a `QListWidget` and `QLineEdit`, but I'd rather it be a direct subclass of `QListWidget` so it can easily replace existing `QListWidgets` in my code and retain all the inherited methods that may be called by the parent widgets.

This is my attempt, but I'm not sure how to put the `QListWidget` inside a layout along with the `QLineEdit`, `layout.addWidget(self)` didn't work.

```
import re
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class SearchableListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, items, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.initial_items = items
        self.set_items(items)

        self.search_box = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.search_box.textChanged.connect(self.filter)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.search_box)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def filter(self):
        filtered_items = [item for item in self.initial_items
                          if re.search(self.search_box.text().lower(), item.lower())]

        self.set_items(filtered_items)

    def get_items(self):
        return [str(self.item(i).text()) for i in range(self.count())]

    def set_items(self, items):
        self.clear()
        for name in items:
            self.addItem(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    test = SearchableListWidget(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    test.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I get:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the structure of your program: The window is SearchableListWidget which is a QListWidget where you placed a QLineEdit through a layout, but the correct thing to do is create a class that inherits from a container like QWidget and there place the QLineEdit and the QListWidget vertically through a QVBoxLayout:

```
import re
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class SearchableWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, items, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.search_box = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.search_box.textChanged.connect(self.filter)

        self.list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.search_box)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)

        self.initial_items = items
        self.set_items(items)

    def filter(self):
        filtered_items = [
            item
            for item in self.initial_items
            if re.search(self.search_box.text().lower(), item.lower())
        ]

        self.set_items(filtered_items)

    def get_items(self):
        return [
            str(self.list_widget.item(i).text())
            for i in range(self.list_widget.count())
        ]

    def set_items(self, items):
        self.list_widget.clear()
        for name in items:
            self.list_widget.addItem(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    test = SearchableWidget(["a", "b", "c"])
    test.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a way to do it as a direct subclass of QListWidget so it can be a replacement for other list widgets, i.e. without having to reimplement the functions of a QListWidget. I'm asking because I'm trying to do the same thing